# Maven error when doing packaging

Tags: java, maven

I am facing issues while trying to execute package goal in POM.xml file for my Maven application. 
I am getting below error while trying to package to jar file

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project codesign-maven-plugin: Error extracting plugin descriptor: 'Goal: version already exists in the plugin descriptor for prefix: getversion
[ERROR] Existing implementation is: com.ios.plugin.VersionMojo
[ERROR] Conflicting implementation is: com.ios.plugin.VersionMojo'
```

My project is checked out from version controlled system and there are some versioned controlled file in my project, it seems they are getting included during execution

Here are my POM.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ios.ccss</groupId>
        <artifactId>ios-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-Beta</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ios-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <name>ios-maven-plugin</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ios.ccss</groupId>
            <artifactId>ios-lib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-Beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/.ade_path/**</packagingExcludes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/.ade_path/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <testExcludes>
                        <exclude>**/.ade_path/**</exclude>
                    </testExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>ios-maven-plugin</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting build/target directories?

Comment: Yes I did all the cleanup before triggering for package task

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Have just faced the same problem, after adding the `@Mojo` annotation to the `MyMojo` (a class derived from the `AbstractMojo` class).

The problematic part of the source code:

```
/**
 * Goal which touches a timestamp file.
 *
 * @goal touch
 *
 * @phase process-sources
 */
@Mojo(name = "touch", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

Please, note both the Javadoc and the `@Mojo` annotation.

## Solution

The solution is to remove the Javadoc for the `MyMojo` class and use only the `@Mojo` annotation.

The resulting source code:

```
@Mojo(name = "touch", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

Source: [jigger mast: Creating a maven plugin with java 5 annotations rather than javadoc tags](http://jiggermast.blogspot.com/2015/07/creating-maven-plugin-with-java-5.html).